# Creating html list from php array

Tags: php, html, mysql, list

I am trying to create a html list from a php array that I've fetched from a SQL query, but no matter what I just get really weird results.

```
$dbf = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM testdb") or die(mysql_error());
$info= mysql_fetch_array($dbf);

  foreach($info as $x) 
  {
  echo '<li>' . $x['name'] . '</li>';
  }
```

Instead of getting the names in my database I get the following values

a

a

d

n

k

I am probably doing something wrong?

Comment: You are using <li> so create dots before name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is **mysql_fetch_array()** only fetches the first row from the result set.

You need to execute mysql_fetch_array in a loop.

```
while($info= mysql_fetch_array($dbf))
{
    echo '<li>' . $info['name'] . '</li>';
}
```

Comment: foreach is also loop in php :)

Comment: Yes but he is running a loop on a variable. Whereas the loop needs to be run on the result set.

Comment: This reply + the comment from Kanishk Dudeja solved my problem. Thanks a lot both of you!

Comment: Thanks. You can mark the answer as accepted by clicking on the tick on the left on the answer.

Answer (score 5):

In your code, you are performing `mysql_fetch_array($dbf)` function only once. This only selects the first row from your result set. What you need to do is send this function as a condition on a `while` loop. Consider the following alterations on your code:

```
$dbf = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM testdb") or die(mysql_error());

  echo '<ul>';

  while( $info = mysql_fetch_array( $dbf, MYSQL_ASSOC ) )
  {
      echo '<li>' . $info[ 'name' ] . '</li>';
  }

  echo '</ul>';
```

In the above code, your `while` loop iterates through each and every tuple that your `SELECT` query produces. That should solve your problem.